# Could not find Variable Text.Color

Tags: elm

When attempting to compile Pong from the Elm tutorial I got an error "Could not find variable Text.color"

```
textGreen = rgb 160 200 160
txt f = leftAligned << f << monospace << Text.color textGreen << toText
msg = "SPACE to start, WS and &uarr;&darr; to move"
```

The error refers to the second line provided where I'm trying to set the Text.color.
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: It's hard to find the root cause without full module source and precise compiler output.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `Text` imported? `import Text` and the code you listed will compile.

Is your `txt` function really the type you expect?

```elm
> txt f = leftAligned << f << monospace << Text.color textGreen << toText`
<function> : (Text.Text -> Text.Text) -> String -> Graphics.Element.Element
```

If so, this will compile and run:

```elm
import Text             exposing (monospace, fromString)
import Color            exposing (rgb)
import Graphics.Element exposing (leftAligned)

textGreen = rgb 160 200 160
txt f = leftAligned << f 
                    << monospace 
                    << Text.color textGreen 
                    << fromString
msg = "SPACE to start, WS and &uarr;&darr; to move"

main = txt identity msg
```